# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Getting an error:

> Cannot read Property of Undefined 'Full_Name' at Object.eval

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>
     <ion-input id="name" name=Full_Name #Full_Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UpdateAddress.Full_Name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

[image]

Code:

[image: UpdateAddress Prop]

Comment: Can you show us `UpdateAddress` prop?

Comment: In your Typescript file, add this line `this.UpdateAddress = {}` inside constructor.

Comment: this.UpdateAddress = {} not working i have already tried this @ArpitKumar

Comment: i have shared the UpdateAddress prop image check it @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @AzharPatel Have posted answer check and let me know

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator) `(?)`:

```
UpdateAddress?.Full_Name
```

Your Code:

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>
     <ion-input id="name" name=Full_Name #Full_Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UpdateAddress?.Full_Name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: You cannot use "?" with angular two-way binding, you will get a parse error

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read Property of Undefined 'Full_Name'

You are reading it in the input:

```
<ion-input id="name" name=Full_Name #Full_Name="ngModel"   [(ngModel)]="UpdateAddress.Full_Name"></ion-input>
```

The error means `UpdateAddress` is `undefined` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

## Fix

Initialize `UpdateAddress` in your model.

Comment: how to Initialize UpdateAddress ?